# Delete entire block, with the prefixes before the opening {

Tags: cursor-motions

[image]

### My problem

Consider a code block prefixed with a few words (function name, for example). The vim cursor is in the middle of the prefix word. The line ends with a `{`, which declares a block which spans a few more lines, till a matching `}`.

I would like to delete the entire block - from the line marked as "24" to the line marked as "7".

### What have I tried

- `d%` deletes from the cursor position onwards, till the end of the block, but keeps the `subgraph c` part intact.
- `d8d` works, but I need to know how many lines does the block span.
- `d%dd` works, but I hope there's a more elegant way that I'm missing

### My Question

How can I delete an entire block, including the entire line in which the block starts, with any prefixes before the opening braces?

Comment: According to your screenshot you use `relativenumber`, so you do know how many lines the block spans. Why do you not want to use a feature you have specifically enabled (by default it is turned off)? Btw I would press `8dd` (i.e. delete 8 lines).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the cursor on the first line, the proper operation is `dV%`.  The `d%` means delete from the next `{` to the matching `}`.

The `V` forces the `d` operator to work **linewise**, rather than **characterwise**.  See (`:h o_v`).

Answer (score 3):

Press `V`, which highlights the line under cursor, then repeatedly `cursor-down` until the block ends (which highlights more lines), then `d` to delete this block.

The advantage is, that you have a visual feedback on what gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks. The downside is that the block might be pretty long, and `d%dd` is faster.